# How to pass data from component to a controller in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a scenario like i have dialog which have a controller and inside the dialog i have component and component template have inputs box and select box etc on change of this inputs i want to pass data to dialog controller.
Please suggest how can i achieve that.Thanks

```html
<md-dialog flex="30">
  <form name="newContactForm" novalidate layout="column" flex="auto">
    <md-toolbar style="min-height:48px;max-height:48px;" class="md-light md-primary">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h3>{{ContactsDialogCtrl.title}}</h3>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-divider class="vertical-divider" style="background-color: #788395;min-height: 48px;"></md-divider>
        <md-button type="submit" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="createaccountDialogCtrl.createNewContactFn(newContactForm.$valid,newContactForm)">
          <md-icon flex class="icon-custom-position material-icons">save</md-icon>
          <md-tooltip>Save Contact</md-tooltip>
        </md-button>
        <md-divider class="vertical-divider" style="background-color: #788395;min-height: 48px;"></md-divider>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="createaccountDialogCtrl.close()">
          <md-icon class="material-icons">close</md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content style="padding:20px; overflow-y:auto;height:78vh;" class="overflow-h" layout="row">

      <createaccount-Componentfor-Bidding account-Details="createaccountDialogCtrl.setaccountParameter(event)"></createaccount-Componentfor-Bidding>
    </md-dialog-content>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

[image]

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('webapp')
        .controller('createaccountDialogController', createaccountDialogController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function createaccountDialogController($mdDialog) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.state = '';
        vm.close = close;
        vm.setaccountParameter = setaccountParameter;

     console.log('inside createaccountDialogController');
     //console.log($state.current.name);
        //getAllbidinformation();
        
        function close() {
            console.log('close');
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        function setaccountParameter(obj)
        {
            console.log(obj);
            console.log('inside setaccountParameter');
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please consider reading the whole documentation for Angular. I seem to remember these questions being discussed there in detail.

Comment: can you share your controller code where you use your dialogController. You want your scope of controller to dialogController or vice-versa?

Comment: Hi sunil,i have shared the controller code.Please check it.Thanks